# How to insert into 2 tables which are dependant on each other

Tags: mysql

I have this 2 tables (MySQL) that are dependent on each other and I don't know what to do when creating a new company as it needs a document type...and a document type needs the id of the company it belongs. I was thinking about asking (in a form) for the document type's info (it has only 2 fields) and then inserting it, but it will trigger a foreign key constraint fail as neither keys exists, right?

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
    id long not null,
    document_type_id long not null
)

CREATE TABLE Document_Type
(
    id long not null,
    company_id long not null
)
```

Which approach should I take?

Comment: first of all - need understand is it trigger or is it constraint? Your structure not include no one no other.

ways for disable triggers and constraint different.

what mysql tools You use? what rights in database have?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't really understand

Comment: what tools for access to mysql You use? what user credentials You have? how help You - if we can't understand HOW TO DO THIS? :)

because - if constraints, You can disable check them, if it triggers - You need edit triggers for make ByPass (not fire them) - for all of this You must have proper rights in database.

Simple - do You have root password?

Comment: well, yes, I meant constraints. The constraint will trigger (not as in I have a trigger, but as in "MySQL won't let me insert and an error will arise") a constraint error. Credentials and tools are irrelevant for this matter =)

Comment: Credentials and tools are irrelevant for this matter =) :-))) if You not have rights for disable constraints - it dose matter :-). and tools - for explain You how to check it easy
if constraints - answer below

Comment: it seems that my questions wasn't clear enough as I meant design-wise. I thought there could be a better way to represent my issue in the data base. I do thank you for the effort though :)

Comment: Does it have to be a circular dependency in the first place?

Comment: @AndriyM A company must have a document type to identify it self and also be able to create different document types for customers, clients, partners etc, but those documents must not be shown to other companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the `document_type_id` column in `Company` and introduce a column called `is_company_document_type` of type `boolean` to the `Document_Type` table. `True` would indicate that this document type is not only created by `company_id` but also belongs to it (or whatever is the meaning of the `Company.document_type_id` reference).

Other document types created by the same `company_id` would have `false` in that column and other entities [you are mentioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122237/how-to-insert-into-2-tables-which-are-dependant-on-each-other?noredirect=1#comment224758_122237) (customers, clients, partners et al.) would reference them.

This way you would be able to create a company first and then create its document type without violating any foreign key relationships. If a company must *always* have a document type, you would probably be ensuring that in your application. Granted, that is not as reliable as a constraint in the database, but at least you would not have to deal with circular dependencies, which, as far as I can see, are hard to handle in MySQL.

Comment: I like this idea, plus, I just realized I have a lot of circular dependecies which I'll try to avoid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with correction after comment from author:

example of procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `udp_insert_company`(`v_id` double, `v_document_type_id` double)
BEGIN
declare v_error_text varchar(200);
set v_error_text = '';

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM document_type where id = v_document_type_id) THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('ERROR - id ', CAST(v_id AS CHAR), ' not found') into v_error_text;
    SELECT v_error_text;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO company VALUES (v_id, v_document_type_id);  
END IF; 

END
```

it just example, You can use any other method for return error code

```
@call `test_db`.`udp_insert_company`(4, 3);

ERROR - id 4 not found
```

Comment: I came to the concussion that what I need is a stored procedure without foreign key checks, insert a company, insert a document type and then set the missing fields :)

Comment: :) it little different, but still simple - IF EXISTS (SELECT ...) THEN

Comment: It will still fail for violating the FK relationship :(

Comment: stop! :) in start questions - no any FK relations provided (and this is was in my original answer). If You HAVE FK constraints - just disable it check in procedure code and enable at the end of procedure

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious that the `document_type_id` was the FK (it's a standard I think?)

Comment: what I need is a stored procedure without foreign key checks, insert a company, insert a document type and then set the missing fields :) – Alejandro Nov 29 at 0:34

main words - without :)

next - t will still fail for violating the FK relationship :( Alejandro yesterday

so - You have FK or not? normal way - include full structure of table (with key and indexes), 

You can combine - all of suggested method - depending from real needs, or explain - completely what help You need. As much more information in question, as much less misunderstanding will be with answer! regards